# My VPS cannot send email

Tags: email, vps

**Webmaster Newbie Question**

I have a low end vps (128MB RAM)running on Debian.I used a [bash script](https://github.com/ilevkov/lowendscript#readme) by ilevkov to setup the site. After some trial and error, I managed to set up a WordPress on it. Just now I found out that my VPS can't send any email. I tested using the WordPress reset password email, and it shows

> The e-mail could not be sent.
>   Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function...

After some Google session I noticed that I can send email from ssh. So I tried

```
mail myemail@gmail.com
Subject: Halo dion
some message
.
```

and the result said

```
EOT
/usr/lib/sendmail: No such file or directory
"/root/dead.letter" 9/243
. . . message not sent.
```

**The question**

How can I fix my VPS mail setting?

Comment: Who is your host and do you have root access?

Comment: I host my VPS in a local Indonesian hosting provider. I do have root access.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve checked it again, should work out of the box.

In case it doesn’t:

- Try this thread: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/users-not-receiving-activation-email
- Try reinstalling Exim4 – “bash setup-debian.sh exim4”
- Try installing Postfix instead Exim.

There is also a new version of lowendscript made by Xeoncross - https://github.com/Xeoncross/lowendscript

Comment: Thank you very much @ILevkov . You are right, there is no problem at all with your script. The problem was actually the pre configured exim4 setup.

Answer (score 1):

From the script's `readme file`:

"Remove excess packages (apache2, sendmail, bind9, samba, nscd, etc) and install the basic components needed for a light-weight HTTP(S) web server..."

So this is your problem. You need to install those packages again, especially sendmail.

Comment: Isn't exim4 is a replacement for sendmail?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to configure a mail server which is more complicated than using a bash script. You can do that following these instructions http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKO4MfOpDVs or setup a plugin in WordPress http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/ which you can then configure with an SMTP server. This is the better option in my opinion because if your mail server isn't configured properly your emails from the server will be flagged as spam. So if you have gmail or another email account (zoho.com) provides free email accounts with your domain. Setup the WordPress plugin and use an SMTP server. Then you'll be good to go

Comment: Will give it a try. How about the limitation? Is there a maximum number of email sent daily? Actually almost all of my websites uses Google Apps for their email. If I use another SMTP server (e.g Google Apps), will it reduce my server load (on action that send an email or 2)? If so, than it will be a good news for me :D.

Comment: You'll have to contact Zoho about any mail sending limits. Though if you're not spamming you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem is not in the bash script by @ILevkov, but on the exim4 pre configuration. Since exim4 is already installed, it isn't being re configured by the script. At least that's what I thought . Please correct me I'm wrong

All I have to do is to remove the previos exim4

```
apt-get purge exim4
```

And then reinstall using @Ilevkov well written bash script

```
bash setup-debian.sh exim4
```

Thank you all for your time.